# Partial response query builder in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to implement the [partial response strategy](https://dev.to/andersonjoseph/what-they-want-is-what-they-get-the-partial-response-strategy-5a0m) in my API requests.

In order to implement it, a `fields` string parameter is added to each requests that indicate which fields we want to get.

I'm trying to build that string in a type-safety way using TypeScript, so given this interfaces:

```
interface Book {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  author: Author;
}

interface Author {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  country: Country;
  publisher:Publisher;
}

interface Country {
  isoCode: string;
  name: string;
}

interface Publisher {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

We could generate the query string like this:

```
// queryBuilder should return the string 'id,name,author(name,country(isoCode),publisher(*))'
const fields = queryBuilder<Book>('id', 'name', {author: ['name', {country: 'isoCode', publisher: '*'}]});

httpClient.get('/books?fields=' + encodeURIComponent(fields));
```

So far I have ended up with this working implementation:

```
function queryBuilder<T>(...props: (keyof T | '*' | { [key: string]: any })[]): string {
  const fields = [];

  for (const prop of props) {
    if (typeof prop === 'object') {
      Object.keys(prop).forEach(propName => fields.push(`${propName}(${Array.isArray(prop[propName]) ? queryBuilder(...prop[propName]) : prop[propName]})`));
    } else {
      fields.push(prop);
    }
  }

  return fields.join(',');
}
```

But **I'm unable the define the signature for the rest `props` parameter that would be type-safe with all the nested types** without using `[key: string]` and `any`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this signature:

```
export type queryBuilderData<T> = (keyof T | (keyof T)[] | '*' | { [P in keyof T]?: queryBuilderData<T[P]> });

export function queryBuilder<T>(...props: queryBuilderData<T>[]): string {
  const fields = [];

  for (const prop of props) {
    if (typeof prop === 'object') {
      Object.keys(prop).forEach(propName => fields.push(`${propName}(${Array.isArray(prop[propName]) ? queryBuilder(...prop[propName]) : prop[propName]})`));
    } else {
      fields.push(prop);
    }
  }

  return fields.join(',');
}
```